# Unable to locate table having summary attribute with new line and white space using beatifulsoup 4 find()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I trying to parse an AWR report to get the long-running SQL information, this report has more than 40 tables in which all tables have the same class but a different summary. For parsing, BS4 on Python was able to locate multiple tables but one table with all the SQL info has a summary with a newline and white space, like as below:

HTML Tag from AWR file:

```
<table border="0" class="tdiff" summary="This table displays the text of the SQL statements which have been
      referred to in the report">
<tbody><tr><th class="awrbg" scope="col">SQL Id
```

I have tried to use the BS4 `find()` to locate this table but it fails everytime. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS4    
awrFile='/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/test/XXXXXXXXXXDB69-1.html'
f_awr = open(awrFile, 'r')
soup  = BS4(f_awr, 'html.parser')
sqlTextInfoTable = soup.find('table', {'summary':'This table displays the text of the SQL statements which have been referred to in the report'})
```

`print(sqlTextInfoTable)` is prints `None`.

Comment: There is extra whitespace between "been" and "referred" in your HTML source. The value must match exactly.

Comment: @BaileyParker there is new line and multiple white space between "been" and "refered" in HTML source, unable to figure how to handle that in BS4 "find()" method

Comment: Well if it is consistent, if you give find the exact same white space it should work. That isn’t very maintainable though. You probably just want to iterate through all tables and check if the summary attribute loosely matches your string (you could replace all consecutive white space with a single space for example). Iterating through 40 tables is no big deal. Especially since bs4 already has to parse them all anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use pandas and `.read_html()` since it has the `<table>` tag?

```
html = '''<table border="0" class="tdiff" summary="This table displays the text of the SQL statements which have been
      referred to in the report">
<tbody><tr><th class="awrbg" scope="col">SQL Id'''


import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_html(html)
sqlTextInfoTable = table[0]
```

So just do:

```
import pandas as pd

awrFile='/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/test/XXXXXXXXXXDB69-1.html'
f_awr = open(awrFile, 'r')
table = pd.read_html(f_awr)
sqlTextInfoTable = table[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print (sqlTextInfoTable)
        0
0  SQL Id
```

Comment: thanks for sol, but unfortunately we have more that 50 tables in this HTML report , all these tables have same class name and no ID only attribute added is summary which is unique. I have written script using BS4 parsing few table. Issue is reading this table as "summary" attribute is having new line and white spaces between "been" and "preferred".
Could you please help in reading table with bs4,

Comment: the '.read_html()' returns the tables as a list of dataframes. Could you iterate through those to get what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can `find_all()` the tables and loop through it like this...

```
import pandas as pd

awrFile='/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/test/XXXXXXXXXXDB69-1.html'
f_awr = open(awrFile, 'r')
soup  = BS4(f_awr, 'html.parser')

for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a css attribute = value selector combination to substring match. Here I use `^` (starts with operator). You could also use `*` (contains) operator.

```
matches = soup.select("table[summary^='this table displays the text of the SQL statements which have been']")
```

Comment: is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Use `re` to search specific text of the summary attribute.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

data='''<table border="0" class="tdiff" summary="This table displays the text of the SQL statements which have been
      referred to in the report">
<tbody><tr><th class="awrbg" scope="col">SQL Id'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
sqlTextInfoTable =soup.find('table', summary=re.compile('This table displays the text of the SQL statements'))
print(sqlTextInfoTable)
```

OR

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
data='''<table border="0" class="tdiff" summary="This table displays the text of the SQL statements which have been
      referred to in the report">
<tbody><tr><th class="awrbg" scope="col">SQL Id'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
sqlTextInfoTable =soup.find('table', summary=re.compile('referred to in the report'))
print(sqlTextInfoTable)
```

Output:

```
<table border="0" class="tdiff" summary="This table displays the text of the SQL statements which have been
      referred to in the report">
<tbody><tr><th class="awrbg" scope="col">SQL Id</th></tr></tbody></table>
```